# Makefile for CGI program using SQLite library

Tags: c, sqlite, makefile

I am developing a CGI program in C on Linux using gcc, GNU make and the SQLite library. How does my makefile look?

```
# Automatic Variables
# $@ file name of target
# $< name of the first prerequisite
# $? name  of all prerequisites newer than target
# $^ names of all prerequisites
# Pattern rule example - complile object files from prerequisites
# %.o: %.c
#   $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 
#
# Predefined Variables  
# CC compiler, default gcc
# CFLAGS compiler flags
# LDFLAGS linker flags such as -L (extra directories searched for -l)
# LDLIBS libaries such as -lfoo

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O2
LDLIBS=-ldl -lpthread
# directory of SQLite library
SQLITEDIR=sqlite

sqlfun.cgi: sqlfuncgi.o sqlite3.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

sqlite3.o: $(SQLITEDIR)/sqlite3.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -c -Os 

sqlfuncgi.o: sqlfuncgi.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -c $(CFLAGS) 

.PHONY: clean test
clean:
    rm -f sqlfun.cgi *.o

test:
    clear
    cppcheck --enable=all --inconclusive --std=c89 sqlfuncgi.c
    valgrind --leak-check=yes ./sqlfun.cgi test
```

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2.

Answer (score 1):

#### First impressions

This is clear and easy to read, and follows conventions well.

---

#### Use more built-ins

You can use more of Make's built-in rules.  For example, this rule can be omitted entirely:

```
sqlfuncgi.o: sqlfuncgi.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -c $(CFLAGS)
```

If you add `$(SQLITEDIR)` to the VPATH, the `sqlite3.o` rule becomes simply

```
sqlite3.o: CFLAGS += -Os
```

And the link rule can use the built-in `LINK.c` variable:

```
sqlfun.cgi: sqlfuncgi.o sqlite3.o
    $(LINK.c) -o $@ $^  $(LDLIBS)
```

---

#### Special targets

Good use of `.PHONY`.  We probably also want `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` to ensure that if any command fails, its partially-written outputs don't hang around and appear to be made

---

#### Portability improvement

We can use Make's predefined `$(RM)` in place of `rm -f`.

Comment: Thanks Toby. As you said, I could have omitted the sqlitefuncgi.o rule since it would be implicitly built - but I find it clearer to have it explicitly documented. I didn't know about VPATH, so I have added it. I also added a system include path since I don't want to see compiler warnings from sqlite/sqlite3.h. I also added your suggestions $(RM) and .DELETE_ON_ERROR. I can't find any documentation about LINK.c - what does it do? Is $(CFLAGS) superfluous in the sqlfun.cgi recipe? I assume this rule only does linking not compiling

Comment: `$(LINK.c)` is one of Make's built-in variables (that can be examined using `make --print-data-base` - which on my system shows it defined as `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)`), and it's used in the default rule for building from C sources.  You'd use `$(LINK.cc)` instead for C++ code, to link the C++ standard library as well.